# Maintaining state when Dynamically building components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-state-management

I'm trying to implement a dynamic component builder, however I'm struggling to find an optimal way to do so:

```
export interface InputDetailMetadata {
  detailMetadata: DetailMetadata,
  stateResolvers: DetailStateResolver[]
}

export interface DetailStateResolver {
  currentValue: any,
  onValueChange: (value: any) => void
}
```

I'm trying to dynamically resolving a component based on its type, I have a detail component that handles iterating over a list of data and generating components like so:

```
detail.detailMetadata.type === DetailField.ADDRESS ? (
  <AddressInput key={key} label={t`${detail.detailMetadata.label}`} value={detail.stateResolvers[0].currentValue} onChange={detail.stateResolvers[0].onValueChange} />
) :
detail.detailMetadata.type === DetailField.Numeric ? (
   <NumericInputPanel key={key} label={t`${detail.detailMetadata.label}`} value={detail.stateResolvers[0].currentValue} onChange={detail.stateResolvers[0].onValueChange} />
) :
null
```

Each one of these components require maintaining state of one or many values, in the past I had the states hard coded for each component:

```
const [toAddressValue, setToAddressValue] = useState('')
const handleToAddressInput = useCallback(
  (toAddress: string) => {
    setToAddressValue(toAddress)
  },
  [setToAddressValue]
)
```

Now I need to store this dynamically for an array, however some of these components may require multiple callbacks/states, and on top of that hook limitations will prevent me from using a switch case on the details.

```
const stateResolvers: InputDetailMetadata[] = details.map(detail => {
  const result = { detailMetadata: detail };
  if (detail.type === ProposalActionDetailField.ADDRESS) {
    const [toValue, setValue] = useState('')
    const onValueChange = useCallback((value: any) => setValue(value), [setValue]);
    result.stateResolvers = [{
      currentValue: toValue,
      onValueChange
    }]
  }
  // handle other types which may require multiple states and callbacks
})
```

My solution won't work for a few reasons of conditional hooks, and I'm skeptical whether I won't need to nest them later.

How can I store state for a dynamic component?

Comment: Have you considered https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: @ksav sorry, I updated the question to be more clear, but I need to manage the state for dynamic components, within react.

Comment: Yes i understand. What do you need to do with the state that can't be achieved with the above?

Comment: I might be able to store it in form data but would that be responsive and plug into native hooks, refreshable etc?